# After close modal not remove fillable data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am working with bootstrap modal when i fill data on form after that i close reopen it but modal still have value. I am using jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
     console.log('testhahah');
     $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
      });
 });
```

above code is not working. My jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/pp7dj2ab/2/

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.removeData()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/) wont reset the form, this function is to:

> The jQuery.removeData() method allows us to remove values that were
>   previously set using jQuery.data(). When called with the name of a
>   key, jQuery.removeData() deletes that particular value; when called
>   with no arguments, all values are removed.

You should use [Form reset() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

```
$(this).find('form')[0].reset();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pp7dj2ab/3/